# C++ Beginner - Trouble using classes inside of classes

Tags: c++, class, header-files, return-type

I am working on a college project, where I have to implement a simple Scrabble game.

I have a `player` class (containing a Score and the player's hand, in the form of a `std::string`, and a `score` class (containing a name and numeric (`int`) score).

One of `Player`'s member-functions is `Score getScore()`, which returns a Score object for that player. However, I get the following error on compile time:

```
player.h(27) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'getScore'
player.h(27) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
player.h(27) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
player.h(27) : warning C4183: 'getScore': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'
player.h(35) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier '_score'
player.h(35) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
player.h(35) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

Here's lines 27 and 35, respectively:

```
Score getScore(); //defined as public
(...)
Score _score; //defined as private
```

I get that the compiler is having trouble recognizing `Score` as a valid type... But why? I have correctly included `Score.h` at the beginning of `player.h`:

```
#include "Score.h"
#include "Deck.h"
#include <string>
```

I have a default constructor for `Score` defined in `Score.h`:

```
Score(); //score.h

//score.cpp
Score::Score()
{
    _name = "";
    _points = 0;
}
```

Any input would be appreciated!

Thanks for your time,

Francisco

EDIT:

As requested, score.h and player.h:
http://pastebin.com/3JzXP36i 
http://pastebin.com/y7sGVZ4A

Comment: Your first error probably occurs on line 26.  Note that the error message indicates "before identifier."  You may wish to include a bit more code.  Also, constructors should be declared inside a class definition.

Comment: I don't think so... That error is thrown because I attempt to define Score as the return type. I have declared constructors correctly. Any suggestions on what code I should include?

Comment: You need to paste more code. Whole `score.h` and first lines of `player.h`

Comment: Hard to tell with just tiny snippets of code, but where is your class definition, and is Score defined when it's being used?

Comment: Include a biger picture of Your code in Your question. If the compiler complains about missing semicolon it's most probably missing semicolon, but if it's not we have to see the code. One thing to learn about C++ is that the first error is the one to fix first. Often subsequent errors come form the first one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've got a circular inclusion problem - relatively easy to fix in this case.

Remove the `#include "Player.h"` from `Score.h`.

---

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281641/circular-c-header-includes) question for an explanation and discussion of what you'd need to do if `Score` actually used `Player`.

---

As for the compiler errors you're getting, that's how Microsoft's compiler reports the use of undefined types -you should learn to mentally translate them all into "Type used in declaration not defined".

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is the *recursive include*: `Score.h` is trying to include `Player.h`, and `Player.h` is trying to include `Score.h`. Since the Score class doesn't seem to actually be using the Player class, removing `#include "Player.h"` from `Score.h` should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have a [circular dependency problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency) : `Score.h` includes `Player.h` and `Player.h` includes `Score.h`.

Do solve this problem, delete your include to `Player.h` in `Score.h` and define `class Player;` if you need to use it in Score class.